# hardware required for wifi security system

Tags: appsec, wifi, rfid

i am planning to implement one WIFI security system , in which one can lock or unlock door remotely.

As i have serched over internet and i came across 
[lockitron](https://lockitron.com) and [schlage](http://consumer.schlage.com/Pages/home.aspx)

Now what i want to know is

1) the physical setup required to implement this project.
I mean what hardware i will be needing to implement it ?

2) Is it possible to use RFID locks which can also be locked and unlocked over internet ?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are wanting to accomplish with this system?

Comment: i want to implement door locking and unlocking system which work on a wireless network

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance at the lockitron web site answers both questions.

The hardware setup involves replacing existing locks with their WiFi connected locks; and they support NFC but not plain RFID.

Answer (score 1):

It is vulnerable! Just a thought... Soon, anybody with a smart-phone, time & intent can, and might try to exploit security flaws within the residential, and enterprise security standards of today's technology...

In real thought, its better to have hardware locks...

@least then they would need a bag of tools...

I've always found "two-factor" authentication to be the best.

So, one hardware(key), one RFID...